# Как присвоить id пользователя файлам, чтобы выводить только те файлы, которые принадлежат этому пользователю

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

Ситуация следующая: делаю что-то наподобие облачного хранилища на ASP.NET Core MVC. Присутствует регистрация пользователей, после которой все зарегистрированные пользователи закидываются в БД Users и им присваивается UserId. Также есть загрузка файлов (ссылки на файлы хранятся в БД Files). Вопрос: как присвоить UserId файлам, которые этот пользователь загрузил? Пока что просто выводятся все файлы, которые были загружены на сервер.

Comment: БД Users и БД Files следует читать как таблица Users и таблица Files?

Comment: Неконкретный вопрос. Что мешает добавить в таблице поле OwnerId?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin да

Comment: Добавьте поле OwnerId/UserId в таблицу Files и заполняйте его при загрузке файлов

Comment: Вам нужна связь многие-ко-многим для ваших таблиц